# What is the meaning of 'to get out of life'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'to get out of life'? I have never heard that phrase before and I wonder what it is supposed to express.It is from a song. The line goes like this:

> don't take life too seriously! Nobody gets out of life anyway.

Comment: Can you provide the context e.g. a full sentence ? And state what you found via Google and why it was inadequate.

Comment: If it's something like "What do you want to get out of life?" then you should be able to make an attempt at understanding the meaning simply from each word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's correctly tagged "meaning-in-context" but no context is supplied. Nor is any evidence of prior research. The question will be re-openable when it's edited to include these.

Comment: In that case it's not an idiom, it's a simple statement that everyone dies eventually.  This is different from the idiom "getting something out of life", which means having some sort of satisfying existence.

Comment: 'You can't get out of doing National Service' (as an example) means there's no way you can avoid doing it.

Comment: Google "get out of definition" to find out about the verb phrase "to get out of".

Comment: I think it is "nobody gets out alive anyway."

Comment: The original quote is "Don't take life too seriously. You'll never get out of it alive." - Elbert Hubbard . Copied by many others e.g Bugs Bunny(!), see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbert_Hubbard#In_popular_culture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording you ask about appears to be a play on the idiomatic tough-guy expression

> Nobody gets out of here alive.

...but it isn't a very good variant because it runs up against another common idiomatic expression:

> What do you want to get out of X?

meaning "What benefit do you hope to gain from X?" A fuller (and clearer) wording of the expression that you ask about would be along the lines of

> Nobody gets out of life alive, anyway.

meaning simply "Everyone dies eventually." It seems a bit odd to juxtapose that rather downbeat assessment of existence with the conclusion that we should therefore not take life too seriously.